# Remove a function defined in a plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I just installed [ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace](https://github.com/ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace) plugin and it defines a EnableWhitespace function which is really annoying since I'm used to typing :E to get the Explorer and now there is a conflict (Ambiguous use of user-defined command).

Is there a way to remove this function in my vim.rc file (i.e. some magical 'unbind_function EnableWhitespace') and leave the plugin code intact?

The plugin also provides a ToggleStripWhitespaceOnSave, so I will not miss any functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't forget `:Explorer` is the same as `:e.`. As a matter a fact you can `:edit` on any directory to open up netrw. If you use Tim Pope's [vinegar.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar) then `-` is already mapped to open the current file's directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`EnableWhitespace` is a user command, not a function (there is a function with that name but that's not relevant). You can delete it with:

```
:delcommand EnableWhitespace
```

Comment: Yes, but if I put that in the .vimrc file i get "No such user-defined command: EnableWhitespace" on launching vim.

Comment: The vimrc is sourced before your plugins, therefore, put that command into a VimEnter autocommand.